# Value error in model.fit() in Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a beginner in Tensor Flow.I'm trying to build a simple model which will try to predict the AND operation of 0 and 1.I have made a small data set with 0 and 1 AND operation which has X1,X2 and output column.I have two variables X and y.
X has dataframe of input1 and input2. y has dataframe of output.The problem is defining neural networks layer using keras.I don't know how to specify the size of the input layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd

dataDF = pd.read_excel('Untitled.xlsx')
dataDF.columns = ['X1','X2','Output']

x = dataDF[['X1','X2']]
y = dataDF[['Output']]

model = keras.Sequential([
         keras.layers.Dense(units=2,input_shape=[2]),
         keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation='relu'),
         keras.layers.Dense(1)           
])

model.compile() #Here i don't know what loss and optimizer i should specify
model.fit(X,y)
```

I get this following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_11 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape [None, 2]
```

The shape of X and y are (15, 2) and (15,1) respectively.

How can i feed X as input to Neural network and what is the input_shape.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace  the `input_shape=[2] to input_shape=(2,)`.Input shape is tuple not list.

Comment: Now after replacing it i was able to train my model.But how can i make predictions using model.predict(). I used model.predict([1,1]) but it gives me this error     ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_17 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape [None, 1]

Comment: How can i feed input to test my model.I'm planing to use it in android app as tflite model.

Answer (score 0):

A Sequential model is appropriate for a plain stack of layers where each layer has exactly one input tensor and one output tensor.
A Sequential model is not appropriate when:

- Your model has multiple inputs or multiple outputs
- Any of your layers has multiple inputs or multiple outputs

If you have 2 inputs then maybe try and use [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/)